# SoundPool, small pause between loops of sound clip

Tags: android, soundpool

I'm using `SoundPool` to play a somewhat short audio clip, and it needs to loop multiple times. I noticed that between the loops, theres a slight pause between the current loop ending and the next one beginning. Is this normal with `SoundPool`? What is the workaround for this?

Heres my current code:

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });


        soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.white_test_v2, 1);
```

then to play it:

```
if (loaded) {
                soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 5, 1f);
                Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
            }
```

where `5` is an `int` specifying the number of loops.

So is this slight pause normal? Is there a solution to prevent it?

Comment: Not normal from my experience.  Are you working with an emulator or an actual device?

Comment: Actual device, nexus 5 running 6.0. Also note, this pause doesnt happen when using `MediaPlayer` with `.setLooping(true).`

Comment: Usually people complain about MediaPlayer and not SoundPool!

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Seem to get the same issue on a geny emulator running 5.0.